# Creating a blender water drop simulation

Tags: animation, fluid-simulation

How to create a simulation where a water (liquid) drop falls in the liquid and bounces back up?
Like shown here:
[image]

I was unable to find any tutorials/guides about this on the internet.

Comment: Have you tried a fluid simulation?

Answer (score 2):

A fluid simulation will not match the reference image exactly but it can create something similar. The splashback is usually more chaotic and the concentric circles are more subtle.

[image: example render]

Animated:

[image: blub animation]

The setup is straightforward. Scale the height of the default cube to half. Use the menu *Object > Quick Effect > Quick Liquid* to create the fluid simulation. Scale and move the domain to match the cube (*water pool*). It's about 2.6 meters tall in the example.

Create a sphere (*water droplet*) and add a *Fluid* physics to it. Set *Type* to `Flow` and *Flow Type* to `Liquid`. Then tick `[X] Initial Velocity` and set *Z* to something like `-9 m/s`. This will shoot the droplet into the water pool and create a splashback.

(Sidenote: For some reason, I couldn't get a proper splashback with an obstacle (*stone*). If you want to try set *Fluid Type* of the droplet to `Effector` and *Settings > Effector Type* to `Collison`). Maybe I did something wrong?)

[image: scene setup]

For the *Liquid Domain* object, I've used a *Settings > Resolution Divisions* value of `72`. This value depends on the initial size of the *Liquid Domain* object (2.0 m x 2.0 m x 2.6 m in the example). The higher you set the *Resolution Divisions* value, the lower the *Initial Velocity* of the drop you need, but the longer the baking time.

You can set *Time Scale* to `0.5` and *Timesteps Minimum* to `2`. Feel free to play around with these numbers and the *CFL Number*.

Then tick `[X] Mesh`. Last but not least, adjust the *Cache* settings, especially the *End Frame*. Set *Type* to `All`, tick `[X] Is Resumable` if you want to interrupt the baking process, and then press the <kbd>Bake All</kbd> button.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But as mentioned, it produces much chaotic splashes!